# SQL Displaying a maximum #ID from the right 3 numbers in ID only for each name in a different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry if the title is confusing.

I am trying to fix a piece of my SQL query that would be able to display only max number of something in another column. for example I have about 100 names and each name has an ID between 1 and 30 sometimes duplicates. I want to display the highest ID only for each of the names including duplicates of the max.

I have tried using top 1() and I am not sure if count() will give me what I need

```
select Coordinates, Name, ID, right(ID,4) as Rightthree

from Coordinates 

where right(ID,4) = max(right(ID,4) for each Name
```

In a perfect world that last line would be all that I need. Is there somewhere that I could start? or is there a better way to rephrase my question to make searching for an answer easier?

Thanks for your help.

Edit- Unfortunately this is sensitive information but I can make a recreation:

say I have

> ```
> name   ID
> ohio   5
> ohio   5
> ohio   6
> Texas  2
> Texas  2
> ```

I want to display

> ```
> name   ID
> ohio   6
> Texas  2
> Texas  2
> ```

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the data in the table along with the desired output?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also, keep in mind that your code is fiddling with the `id`, but your problem descriptions says nothing about taking the first 3 or 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your problem:

> *I want to display the highest ID only for each of the names*

Then simply do:

```
select name, max(id)
from coordinates
group by name;
```

If this isn't the solution to your problem, then please express the question more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can join to a derived table (subquery with an alias).

```
select blah, blah
from coordinates join 
(select name, max(right(id, 4)) id
from coordinates
group by name ) temp on temp.name = coordinates.name
and temp.id = right(coordinates.id, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

try with Correlated subquery

```
select C1.Name, C1.ID, right(C1.ID,4) as Rightthree from Coordinates C1
where right(C1.ID,4) = (Select max(right(C2.ID,4)) from from Coordinates C2 where C2.Name=C1.Name)
```